# Can I use id's in React to allow individual element matching with enzymes containsMatchingElement?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

How do you reference a React element using enzymes `containsMatchingElement` if there is multiple occurrences of the React element? Should each element have an ID which is referenced instead?

To use an example:

I have a simple component for rendering three 'animals' each inside a row. The component has a single prop called `show_mouse` which will hide and show the `Row` containing the mouse. The unit test `containsMatchingElement` will match all of the `Row` components instead of the only one I am interested in. Should I be adding a unique id to each row for example `id="row-mouse` which I can reference in Enzyme? I'm just not sure if this is the 'React' way

**Animal.jsx**

```
type PropTypes = {
    show_mouse: boolean,
};

export default function Animal(props: PropTypes) {

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <div>Cat</div>
            </Row>
            { props.show_mouse ? (
                <Row>
                    <div>Mouse</div>
                </Row>
                ) : "" }
            <Row>
                <div>Dog</div>
            </Row>

        </>
    );
}


OptionExercisePeriods.defaultProps = {
    show_mouse: '',
};
```

**Animal.jest.js**

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import Animal from '../Animal';


describe('Animal component test', () => {

    test("Mouse hides and shows", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Animal show_mouse={true} />);

        expect(
            wrapper.containsMatchingElement(
                <Row>,
            ),
        ).toBeTruthy();

        wrapper.setProps({show_mouse: false});

        expect(
            wrapper.containsMatchingElement(
                <Row>,
            ),
        ).toBeFalsy();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, of course, use "id" for unique identifiers. Otherwise you can still put a className to the Row element and match that in your tests. Both are valid solutions.

In your test you can simply find the element using css selector and making sure it is rendered by doing:

```
expect(wrapper.find('Row.myClassName').exists()).toBe(true);
```

Or using Id with

```
expect(wrapper.find('Row#myIdName').exists()).toBe(true);
```

Also, if you want to make sure you are rendering the correct child block inside, you can also use the text helper like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find('Row').text()).toBe("Cat");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing an exists check using the ID.

`expect(wrapper.exists('#myIdName')).toBe(true);`

Building on @andreasonny83 answer.